# Which Analyzer can meet my need in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In my situation, my field is like "abc,123", I want it can be searched either "abc" or "123".
my index mapping is just like the code below

```
{
"myfield": {
   "type": "text",
   "analyzer": "stop",
   "search_analyzer": "stop"                }
```

But when I use es *_analyzer* API to test, I got the result

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "abc",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

"123" was lost.
If I want to meet my situation, do I need to choose some other analyzer or just to add some special configs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose `standard` analyzer instead as `stop` analyzer breaks text into terms whenever it encounters a character which is not a letter and removes stop words like 'the'. In your case "abc,123" results in token abc when using stop analyzer. Using standard analyzer it returns abc and 123 as shown below

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "abc, 123"
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "abc",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "123",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT1** Using Simple Pattern Split Tokenizer

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "simple_pattern_split",
          "pattern": ","
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "abc,123"
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "abc",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "123",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, if i use the standard analyzer, the chinese word will encounter a problem, just like "北京"， it will become "北" and "京". In fact，I just want these words can be split by comma, and every word can be indexed

Comment: Use a Simple Pattern Split Tokenizer then to split by comma. Updated my answer